# simple JSONP & PHP example not working

Tags: php, jsonp

Been trying to create a simple JSONP call but it doesn't always work and I dunno why. Here's the code:

server-side (`http://server/server.php`):

```
<?php
    $res = json_encode("It works!");

    if(isset($_GET['callback']) === TRUE) {
        header('Content-Type: text/javascript;');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://client');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
        echo $_GET['callback']."(".$res.");";
    } else {
        echo $res;
    }
?>
```

client-side (`http://client/client.html`):

```
<html>
    <head><title>JSONP</title></head>
    <body>
        <h1>JSONP Experiment</h1>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function process(data) {
                $('#result').text(data);
            }

            $.getJSON(
                'http://server/server.php?callback=?',
                {'callback': 'process'}
            );

        </script>
        <p id="result"></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

This code works and displays "It works!" in my

block.

- Why isn't it working when I dont use `{'callback': 'process'}` and put ?callback=process straight into the $.getJSON() URL?
- Why isn't it working if I use `<script src="http://server/server.php?callback=process"></script>` instead of the $.getJSON() call?

Both not-working cases actually return `process("It works");` but this isn't executed, why?

Thanks

Comment: Note that `echo $_GET['callback']` is really not a great idea. You should ensure that the function name is a valid JS identifier.

Comment: @lonesomeday It doesn't really pose a security risk though. And if the code sends something that isn't a valid JS identifier then all that will happen is it simply won't work - the only thing that could be achieved would be to break it, and that would only affect the calling client, so basically the attacker would do nothing but screw themselves over.

Comment: @DaveRandom It's a potential XSS hole. More importantly, failure events should be handled with error responses. In this case, `400 Bad Request`. But this is a side point to the question.

Comment: @lonesomeday The fact that it's a direct (and not stored) echo back, combined with SOP, *should* negate the XSS vulnerability (unless I'm missing something?) but I agree completely about handling errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The are two different issues here, with different answers

---

The reason it doesn't work when you use `$.getJSON()` and put the name of the callback literally in the URL is because of the way in which jQuery works.

Firstly lets look at how jQuery detects that your `$.getJSON()` call is expecting JSONP if you don't pass any options that indicate it explicitly in the settings object - it [uses](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/jsonp.js#L2) this regular expression:

```
/(=)\?(?=&|$)|\?\?/
```

This looks explicitly for either `=?` in the query string or a query string consisting of nothing but a single `?` - in essence, the question mark is required for detecting that the URL will return JSONP.

Without it, jQuery makes an Ajax request using XHR and the correct data is returned by the server. What happens next depends on the Same Origin Policy. If, like the code you show, the server indicates via `Access-Control-*` headers that the request is allowed, the data will be accessible just liek it would be with an Ajax request to the client's origin server. If these headers are not present, the data returned will not be accessible to the client code.

But, crucially, because it just makes a standard Ajax request and does not add a `<script>` element to the DOM, it means that the response text is never evaluated as Javascript code - the crucial last-step in the JSONP mechanism.

---

The second version is a little trickier to answer and know that the answer is correct with the information provided, but with the HTML layout you show above I'm reasonably confident this is the reason: Your HTML elements are defined in the wrong order.

When processing the DOM on page load, processing halts at every `<script>` element while the associated Javascript is synchronously loaded and processed. This is to ensure that all Javascript is executed in the intended order, and that any calls to things which directly modify the DOM in a location specific way - such as `document.write()` (which you should *never* use, in case you don't know) - are honoured correctly.

The upshot of this is that if you placed the `<script>` element in the DOM *before* the `<p id="result">` tag, the result tag doesn't actually exist at the point where the `process()` function is called. And because you used a jQuery selector instead of `document.getElementById()`, it swallows the error that would have resulted if you had tried to modify it directly.

This is the reason that many Javascript developers (including myself) will now tell you that you should place your `<script>` tags as the very last elements in the `<body>`, as it gives a perceived performance improvement - even though in reality it takes exactly the same amount of network time to load and process all the page resources, it allows the browser to render the page quicker. Doing this also negates the need to use things like `$(document).ready()`/`DOMContentLoaded` events to delay execution (which, incidentally, would also solve this problem, but in a slightly messier way).

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I now understand better how getJSON() works. So I guess my usage is correct with callback=? and a 'callback' parameter set to whatever function I wanna call.

Also I usually place JS scripts at the end of my HTML body, or at least use a $(document).ready(), but I made it the other way this time. I also tried to use document.getElementById() first, and didn't realize why I got a NULL object. I guess it's too hot in here and my brain's malfunctioning.

Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: I updated my code and put the <p> before my <script>'s. I also use the <script> way instead of getJSON() and it seems to be working without the header()'s on the server side. But maybe I should at least leave the header('Content-Type......)?

Comment: @gael The use of JSONP negates the need for the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:` headers, these are used to allow regular Ajax requests (in browsers that support it). The `Content-Type:` header should definitely be included, and just FYI, the correct media-type for JSON is (will be eventually when it gets standardised) `application/json`.

Comment: @gael If this answer helped you, please don't forget to [upvote it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: @DaveRandom alright but actually, what my server.php returns isn't JSON data, it's javascript, as the JSON data are surrounded with the callback function? or am I completely wrong?

Comment: @gael Exactly - what your server is returning is actually a Javascript statement, which means that in order for the callback function to be invoked, it must be evaluated as JS code. If you do it with a `<script>` tag (this is how JSONP is usually implemented) this happens automatically. If you use regular Ajax, you'd need to `eval()` it (or manually create a `<script>` tag with the result as the content and add it to the DOM) - but if this is the case, you may as well not bother with the JSONP and just fetch JSON, which can then be passed to `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @DaveRandom fair enough. my question about JSON/JS was about the content-type header(). I'm wondering, as it returns a call to a JS function, whether it should be application/json or text/javascript?

Comment: @gael That's a very valid point that I've never considered before. It's true, for JSONP you should use `application/javascript` and for JSON you should use `application/json`, because they are the media-type specifications that accurately describe the content, and the way they will be handled on the client side.